# SQL Rewriting Tips

Tags: mysql, sql, max, having, having-clause

I wrote this query on MySQL:

```
select a.customer_id,b.first_name,sum(a.amount) as top from payment a
left JOIN customer b on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
group by a.customer_id order by top desc limit 1;
```

Is there any way I can avoid limit clause and get max(sum(a.amount)) ?
I tried the below but getting invalid group by error ?

```
select a.customer_id,b.first_name,sum(a.amount) as top from payment a
left JOIN customer b on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
group by a.customer_id having max(sum(a.amount));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the limit is better, unless you want to return all the maximum records.

So the statement may like this:

```
select a.customer_id,b.first_name,sum(a.amount) as top from payment a
  left JOIN customer b on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
  group by a.customer_id 
  having sum(a.amount) = 
    (select max(top1) from 
      (select a.customer_id,b.first_name,sum(a.amount) as top1 from payment a
        left JOIN customer b on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
        group by a.customer_id 
        ) as tmp
    );
```

If mysql can support temporary table like mssql, you don't have to repeat your sum twice.

Comment: You need to add b.first_name to the group by, as it's not an aggregate function. Otherwise you will still get the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: I know, but I tested in sqlfiddle, it works in mysql. I didn't fix it, just to keep the original statement that the OP gave as possible as I can.

Comment: Jaugar, This query works and gets the result, However, This creates temptable and performs filesort which is kind of performance hit on database.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
select customer_id, first_name, top from (
  select a.customer_id,b.first_name,sum(a.amount) as top from payment a
  left JOIN customer b on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
  group by a.customer_id
) as t
having top = max(top)
```

I think the limit is fine though, might be faster.

Comment: This will still give a group by error, as first_name needs to be part of the group by statement

Comment: @JanR - no it won't, because this is MySQL.  Presumably there's only one `customer` record (with a single `first_name` value), so he's fine, but otherwise this is potentially a dangerous "feature".